# Call value onclick checkbox Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I need to improve onclick function for checkbox. When click the checkbox `contenteditable` cell should be **crossed** . How can I do this? Thanks for all response.
 My simple code following as like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
     table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        margin: 100px;
    }
    table, td, th {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 10px;
    }
        table td.crossed {
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent calc(50% - 1px), red, transparent calc(50% + 1px));
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="t1">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1.</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="date" id="mydate">
        </td>
            <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    </tr>
</table>

 <script> 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: There should be like this picture]

Comment: Where is your javascript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By lack of classes or IDs, you can use the `querySelector` to get the appropriate elements:

```
var cb = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
var td = document.querySelector("td[contenteditable]";

cb.addEventListener("click", function(){
    td.className = td.className + " crossed";
});
```

This will only work for >IE8

Comment: It would be easier to do `querySelector()` instead of `querySelectorAll()[0]`